# Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: asp.net, hiddenfield

here's a portion of my code:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hdnLocationLatLng" runat="server" Value="0" />
```

and I'm trying to set the value of hdnLocationLatLng to the value of the latlng of the marker's current position, using this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                            if (marker) {
                                marker.setMap(null);
                            }

                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: event.latLng,
                                map: map,
                                draggable: true,
                                title: "My Event's Location",
                            });

                            document.getElementById("#<%= hdnLocationLatLng.ClientID %>").value = marker.getPosition();
                        });
```

but everytime I click on the map, I got the error:

```
Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set property 'value' of null.
```

FYI, I can get the value of marker.getPosition() without any problem (tried to display it in alert and it returns the right value).

Comment: Where does that error occur? On what line?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, it says the error are on the line "document.getElementById("#<%= hdnLocationLatLng.ClientID %>").value = marker.getPosition();"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("#<%= hdnLocationLatLng.ClientID %>")
```

Remove # char